# generate sequence of numbers in R according to other variables

Tags: r, variables, sequence

I have problem to generate a sequence of number according on two other variables.
Specifically, I have the following DB (my real DB is not so balanced!):

```
ID1=rep((1:1),20)
ID2=rep((2:2),20)
ID3=rep((3:3),20)
ID<-c(ID1,ID2,ID3)
DATE1=rep("2013-1-1",10)
DATE2=rep("2013-1-2",10)
DATE=c(DATE1,DATE2)
IN<-data.frame(ID,DATE=rep(DATE,3))
```

and I would like to generate a sequence of number according to the number of observation per each ID for each DATE, like this:

```
OUTPUT<-data.frame(ID,DATE=rep(DATE,3),N=rep(rep(seq(1:10),2),3))
```

Curiously, I try the following solution that works for the DB provided above, but not for the real DB!

```
IN$UNIQUE<-with(IN,as.numeric(interaction(IN$ID,IN$DATE,drop=TRUE,lex.order=TRUE)))#generate unique value for the combination of id and date
PROG<-tapply(IN$DATE,IN$UNIQUE,seq)#generate the sequence
OUTPUT$SEQ<-c(sapply(PROG,"["))#concatenate the sequence in just one vector
```

Right now, I can not understand why the solution doesn't work for the real DB, as always any tips is greatly appreciated!

Here there is an example (just one ID included) of the data-set:

```
  id       date
  1  F2_G 2005-03-09
  2  F2_G 2005-06-18
  3  F2_G 2005-06-18
  4  F2_G 2005-06-18
  5  F2_G 2005-06-19
  6  F2_G 2005-06-19
  7  F2_G 2005-06-19
  8  F2_G 2005-06-19
  9  F2_G 2005-06-20
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one using `ave`:

```
OUT <- within(IN, {N <- ave(ID, list(ID, DATE), FUN=seq_along)})
```

Comment: +1 Really great solution, and I urge the OP to accept this as the answer instead because it is more flexible when the input data changes.

Comment: Thank you @Arun for this solution, so basically I discovered two other useful function in R. I really appreciate all the helps from the members!

Comment: Unfortunately both solutions don't work...For the SimonO101 solution R reports that the length of the vector is not matching the DB, whilst for the @Arun solution R reports not valid factor. May be the problem  is related to the format of date?

Comment: For the Arun solution this is what R reports                                            In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1L) :livello non valido in factor, sono stati generati degli NA>translation from italian>not valid level in factor, generate NA                                                                
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1:7): the same as above

Comment: For the Simon solution: when I try to cbind the new variables R reports :arguments have different number of rows. 
Sorry for the delay Arun.

Comment: stefano, sorry for the delay in what?

Comment: But I would like to have the actual data with which you got this error. Am I not communicating properly? :)

Comment: Sorry Arun, my fault!I didn't understand you wanted the actual data. I am preparing it!

Comment: @Arun, I edit the question to provide an example of the data-set.

Comment: It seems like the problem is because the columns are factors. Change them to `character` (you can use the parameter `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` while loading using `read.table` or creating a `data.frame`). Alternatively, if you want to convert **all** columns to character, then just do: `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)` and then try the `ave` line.

Comment: @Arun, you are right!The problem was that the columns were considered as factor. Once again, thank you so much for your help!I really appreciate!All the best, Stef

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want...

```
require(reshape2)
as.vector( apply( dcast( IN , ID ~ DATE , length )[,-1] , 1:2 , function(x)seq.int(x) ) )
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6
 [27]  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2
 [53]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Bascially we use `dcast` to get the number of observations by ID and date like so

```
dcast( IN , ID ~ DATE , length )
  ID 2013-1-1 2013-1-2
1  1       10       10
2  2       10       10
3  3       10       10
```

Then we use `apply` across each cell to make a sequence of integers as long as the count of ID for each date. Finally we coerce back to a vector using `as.vector`.

Comment: Thank you so much @SimonO101 for the detailed description of the solution! I didn't know the existence of dcast function of package reshape2 until your suggestion! Once again, many thanks!

Comment: Hi stefano. No problem, but actually you should accept Arun's solution. I made a more complicated dataset where the lengths of the dates and ID variables are different and my solution will need some modification to make it work properly (if you want to cbind the vector to the original dataframe), but Arun's works perfect. Accept his solution instead. Cheers